# Is it possible to preserve toggles in Inline CSS or do some other trick to send collapsible sections in emails?

Tags: html, css, email

I have little experience in HTML so I apologize if this question has already been answered.

I want to send an email that has a few very long sections so I want them to be collapsible.  I don't know much html/css but I was able to put something together that collapses the sections.  However, whenever I convert it to inline css, I can no longer view the sections that are displayed.

I am open to other ideas on collapseable sections, however, I cannot use regular css, anything that falls under , any javascript, and anything in external documents.

Sample code below

```html
    <head>
      <style>
        body {
          font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
          background: #CCC;
        }
    
        main {
          background: #EEE;
          width: auto;
          margin: 20px auto;
          padding: 10px 0;
          box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
    
        h2 {
          text-align: center;
        }
    
        p {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
    
        input {
          display: none;
          visibility: hidden;
        }
    
        label {
          display: block;
          padding: 0.5em;
          text-align: center;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
          color: #444;
        }
    
        label:hover {
          color: #000;
        }
    
        label::before {
          font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 15px;
          content: "+";
          vertical-align: text-top;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          margin-right: 3px;
          background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%);
        }
    
        #expand0 {
          height: 0px;
          overflow: hidden;
          transition: height 0.5s;
          background: #FFF;
          color: #000;
        }
    
        section {
          padding: 0 20px;
        }
    
        #toggle0:checked~#expand0 {
          height: 85px;
        }
    
        #toggle0:checked~label::before {
          content: "-";
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <main>
      <input id="toggle0" type="checkbox" checked>
      <label for="toggle0">Example</label>
      <div id="expand0">
        <section>
          <p><a href="https://coubsecure-s.akamaihd.net/get/b179/p/coub/simple/cw_timeline_pic/3022e666160/33576a2d011ddb7a1b1a2/big_1499702421_image.jpg">Hello There</a></p>
          <p><a href="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ClosedLastAtlanticsharpnosepuffer-poster.jpg">General Kenobi</a></p>
        </section>
      </div>
     
    </main>
```

Inline of Example

```html
<main style="background-color:#EEE;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;width:auto;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);" >
          <input id="toggle0" type="checkbox" checked style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" >
          <label for="toggle0" style="display:block;padding-top:0.5em;padding-bottom:0.5em;padding-right:0.5em;padding-left:0.5em;text-align:center;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#CCC;color:#444;" >Example</label>
          <div id="expand0" style="height:0px;overflow:hidden;transition:height 0.5s;background-color:#FFF;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;color:#000;" >
            <section style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px;" >
              <p style="font-size:16px;" ><a href="https://coubsecure-s.akamaihd.net/get/b179/p/coub/simple/cw_timeline_pic/3022e666160/33576a2d011ddb7a1b1a2/big_1499702421_image.jpg">Hello There</a></p>
              <p style="font-size:16px;" ><a href="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ClosedLastAtlanticsharpnosepuffer-poster.jpg">General Kenobi</a></p>
            </section>
          </div>
         
        </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because you can't specify inline styles for `checked` status. 
You have to use css for that.

On another note: You say that you want to use this in an email, I don't think any email client would render your collapsible content.

So to answer your question: You have to use CSS (file or tag) for this type of behaviour, it's not possible with inline CSS alone. If you want to send this via email it would be better to dismiss these collapsible elements altogether and maybe reduce the amount of stuff you send out in an email.